# Fourier transform of $1/k^4$

Tags: physics, fourier-transform, mathematical-physics

I am dealing with a physics problem and I have to perform the following integral,

\begin{equation}
\int \dfrac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{e^{ikr}}{k^4}
\end{equation}

I know that if the exponent in the denominator was a 2, the result is the Coulomb potential $1/(4\pi r)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory), but I didn't found anything about a 4 in the denominator.
Does anybody know the result of this integral?

Comment: Perhaps you can use $\mathcal{F}\{fg\} = 2\pi\,\mathcal{F}\{f\}*\mathcal{F}\{g\},$ where $*$ denotes convolution. Take $f=g=k^{-2}.$

Comment: $d^3k/k^4$ goes like $1/k$.

Comment: @cosmo5 Yes, we can see that from dimensional analysis, $k$ and $r$ have opposite dimensions in order to make the exponent dimensionless. Since $[r]=L$ we conclude $[k]=L^{-1}$ and then $[d^3k]/[k^4]=1/[k]=L$ so the result must be linear with $r$.

Comment: In the exponent, do you mean $k_j r_j$ or $|k|r$?